# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).fullCalendar is not a function when trying to remove event source

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I'm trying to get fullCalendar to remove its previous event source and rebind to a new one on buttonclick. I've been searching for an answer for hours now but none of the solutions that I have found seem to work.

I have a page that is a dropdown menu and button above a fullCalendar cal. On page load the calendar loads all the event listings from a db without issue. what i'm trying to implement is a clientside filter that will only display the name(s) I have selected on the dropdown once the button is clicked.

The function to filter the names into a new array of JSON is working perfectly, my issue is that i'm getting a console error as per the title that is stopping me from removing the original source and rebinding the new array.

here's my code:

CSHTML:

```
<div class="member-filter-section">
        <div class="member-filter-container">
            <div class="staff-container">
                <p class="staff-name">Staff Member:</p>
                <div class="staff-select">
                    <select id="staff_list" multiple="multiple">
                        @foreach (var u in users)
                        {
                            <option value="@u.UserId">@u.UserName</option>
                        }
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="branch-container">
                <p class="branch-name">Branch:</p>
                <div class="branch-select">
                    <select id="branch_list">
                        <option>City Center</option>
                        <option>Foxrock</option>
                        <option>Dalkey</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="filter" class="nav_button filter-button">Select</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="calendar-wrapper">
        <div id="calendar" class="calendar-body"></div>
    </div>
```

JS:

```
// The ajax to return a correct JSON array
        var eventsFeed = function (start, end, timezone, callback) {
            var id = @agentId;
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/SystemManagement/Viewings/GetCalendarEventListings",
                data: { 'agentId' : id ,'start' : start.format(), 'end' : end.format()},
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(data) {
                    var events = [];
                    $.each(data,
                        function(obj) {
                            var eventObject = data[obj];
                            events.push({
                                title: eventObject.Title,
                                start: eventObject.StartTime,
                                end:  eventObject.EndTime,
                                id: eventObject.Id,
                                userId: eventObject.UserId,
                                color: eventObject.AppointmentColour,
                                attendee: eventObject.Attendee,
                                location: eventObject.Location,
                                type: eventObject.AppointmentType
                            });
                        });
                    globalEvents = events;
                    callback(events);
                    events = [];
                },
                error: function() {
                    console.log('Error');
                }
            });
        }

        $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#staff_list').chosen();
                $('#branch_list').chosen();

                // Gets the JSON array to populate the calendar on page load
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                    defaultView: 'agendaDay',
                    header: {
                        left: 'prev,next, today',
                        center: 'title',
                        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
                    },
                    height: 850,
                    events: eventsFeed,
                    eventClick: function(calEvent) {
                        buildModal(calEvent.type,calEvent.location,calEvent.attendee,calEvent.color, calEvent.start, calEvent.end);
                        modal.style.display = "block";
                    }
                });

                $('#filter')
                   .on('click',
                       function() {

                           var selectedStaffIds = $("#staff_list").val();
                           var filteredEvents = [];

                           globalEvents.forEach(function(obj) {
                               if (checkIfIdIsSelected(selectedStaffIds, obj.userId)) {
                                   filteredEvents.push(obj);
                               }
                           });
                           console.log(filteredEvents);
                           rebindCalendar(filteredEvents);
                           filteredEvents.length = 0;
                       });

                function checkIfIdIsSelected(staffId, objectId) {
                    return staffId.indexOf(objectId) > -1;
                }

                function rebindCalendar(eventsArray) {
                    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEventSource', eventsFeed);
                    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', eventsArray);
                }
```

Comment: @rocinate i thing script reference of fullcalendar is remove ,,

Comment: Does $('#calendar') actually contain any elements in rebindCalendar?

Comment: @BassT I'm honestly not sure? I'm pretty new to Javascript and was just following the documentation and what I've seen others implement online

Comment: Go ahead and add console.log($('#calendar').length) as first line in the rebindCalendar function for starters. Should be 1.

Comment: @BassT Thanks for the help. Yeah, the length is 1

Comment: Try running it with either the 'removeEventSource' or the 'addEventSource' line commented out. Is there an error everytime?

Comment: Yeah there's an error each time, it also errors when I try removeEvents and removeEventSources without specifying a source.

Comment: So somehow the fullCalendar widget gets lost I guess. Can you try storing the DOM element in a var (like `$calendar = $('#calendar')`) before populating the calendar and reuse it in the rebindCalendar func?

Comment: @BassT you're my hero, that worked! how can I upvote you and mark this as answered?

Comment: Just posted the answer. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So somehow the fullCalendar widget gets lost I guess. Try storing the DOM element in a var (like `$calendar = $('#calendar')`) before populating the calendar and reuse it in the rebindCalendar func.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/drx389j5/

If your `#calendar` does not exists, it means it is somehow removed from the DOM or its ID is changed, or you are trying to manipulate it from another document (in an iframe), or $ is not jQuery, or fullCalendar is destroyed by a function.